# jHipster what order to create entities

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to start an application and my idea was to rattle off the entities first using the command line and then work on the UI. This is proving trickier than I first thought because under certain circumstances you get a warning saying the generator won't work. It's things like whether it's a OneToMany or a ManyToOne or whether this entity is the owning side of the relationship.

What's the best way around this?

If I can work out the rules then I can maybe decide what order to create things in. My worry is that with a complicated schema there is no order that can work without some warnings and things not working.

My other idea was to generate the entities without relationships first and then edit the json files to add the relationships. Then maybe I can run the generator again on each entity. Not sure if that would work though and I'm not 100% sure of the correct json properties required.

What have other people tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Plan your entities and relationships, so that when you create an entity all the entities it depends on have already been created. One way to do this is use a schema designer or just document the entities and put them in the order they need to be created.

Otherwise, as you know, you'll have to manually wire those relationships, or recreate them with the entity generator.

But, even with planning, you're going to have to use a mixture of these methods in the real world. It just depends on how much you've modified the generated code as to which method is the fastest.

Answer (score 4):

Rori's answer is basically what I did but I wanted to provide some extra detail.

First I went through the generator and created every type of relationship to see which ones worked and which ones gave a warning. I was finding that sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't but it wasn't documented anywhere why.

These relationships always work.
OneToMany
OneToOne (not owner)
ManyToMany (not owner)

These relationships only work when the other entity already exists.
ManyToOne
OneToOne (owner)
ManyToMany (owner)

The reason they don't work is always the same. All of these require a foreign key to be created on the other table which jHipster can't do if it doesn't exist yet. You could of course ignore the warning but I wasn't sure if this meant anything else wouldn't work.

Based on these rules I made a list of my entities and put them into an order that would work without warnings. If an entity had a relationship that may give a warning then I just made sure the other entity was created first.

This seems to have worked. The only thing I've found is that because the generator is a one time thing (you can't use it to modify an entity), you have to know your schema up front and generate the lot in one go.